# How to execute a determinated quantity of threads every n milliseconds?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have the following code that executes 5 arrays of 10 threads in each one.

The problem is that this code waits for the 10 threads to finish before executing 10 more threads in other array.

I want a method that executes the array every n milliseconds regardless whether the last 10 are finished or not.

```
@idx = 0

begin
    @threads = Array.new
    10.times do
        @threads << Thread.new{do something}
    end

    @threads.each{|t| t.join}
    @idx += 1
end until @idx == 5
```

Comment: Um, your using join method, it always waits then, till the threads done.

Comment: I cannot parse your sentences.

Comment: What are you trying to do with all this Federico?

Comment: With this code I'm executing ten threads concurrently that do something special and when all these threads end, I execute the same again until the counter '@idx' comes to 5.
I want to do the same but without waiting the finalization of the threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread#join` blocks until the thread finishes. Don't call it. Use `sleep` to pause the current thread for a certain number of seconds.

```
5.times do |idx|
  10.times { Thread.new { something... } }
  sleep n / 1000.0
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Max. I had another concept about Thread#join.